# php - converting csv into array using str_get_csv without physically uploading

Tags: php, arrays

I'm just trying to upload a csv file and convert it to an array.

I've read on a previous post here that you can use str_getcsv() without having to physically upload the csv file to the server.

Is this correct or do I have to store the file somewhere first before I can run str_getcsv() and then delete it afterwards?

Here's my simple code at the moment (I'm using php 5.3):

```
if (isset($_POST['file_upload'])){
    $csv = str_getcsv($_POST['csvfile']);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($csv);
echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: you obviously have to upload the file since u cant access it otherwise, but you dont have to save the uploaded file, it will be uploaded into the php tmp folder and deleted after your script is finished

Comment: Ahh, I was not aware of the tmp directory at all. I'll look into that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$_FILES` array to check file upload.
Use this code:

```
if(isset($_FILES["csvfile"])) {
    $csv=str_getcsv(file_get_contents($_FILES["csvfile"]["tmp_name"]));

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($csv);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much! Before I started this I never realised it was so easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

By default the file is stored in a temp directory which can be accessed by `$_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']`:

As you can see, the first parameter of [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) method must be a string and for this you can use `file_get_contents`

```
$csv = str_getcsv(file_get_contents($_FILES['csvfile']['tmp_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a file (using `<input type="file">`), you will need to use [`move_uploaded_file()`](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file). The file is already on disk (if the form submit was succesful), you just need to move it. In this case, it is most convenient to use [`fgetcsv()`](http://be1.php.net/fgetcsv) which opens the file and parses it into arrays as you go (see the example in the documentation for that function).

If you are not submitting a file but a text using, for example, `<textarea></textarea>`, then you do not have to write the string in the `$_POST` variable to disk but can use [`str_getcsv`](https://www.php.net/str_getcsv) to parse the string into an array.